# How to use CreateProcess or ShellExecute to execute piped commands

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mplayer

I want to execute a few commands piped without new `cmd` opened (so I can't just use `system()`)
This is the command I try to execute:

```
C:\\openssl.exe enc -aes-128-ofb -d -in C:\\encrypted.bin -iv a2b050be9463 -K 6ba62eb7bb2ccace -nopad | C:\\\\mplayer.exe -"
```

This is what I tried :

```
WCHAR prog[] = L"C:\\openssl.exe";
WCHAR args[] = L"enc -aes-128-ofb -d -in C:\\encrypted.bin -iv a2b050be9463 -K 6ba62eb7bb2ccace -nopad | C:\\mplayer.exe -";

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess(prog, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

And it didn't work (There is no error, its just not opening)

I also tried this:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
HINSTANCE hinstRun1 = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"cmd.exe", str2.c_str(), L"", SW_HIDE);
CoUninitialize();

//str2 == C:\\openssl.exe enc -aes-128-ofb -d -in C:\\encrypted.bin -iv a2b050be9463 -K 6ba62eb7bb2ccace -nopad | C:\\\\mplayer.exe -")
```

This is also not working (Again there is no error, its just not opening)

When I tried it like this :

```
system(("cmd.exe /c " str2).c_str());
```

Everything works good (Except the part that its opened also a `cmd` window.)

How can I execute this line from c/c++ program without new `cmd` window?

Comment: Check [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You have a couple of options. You can ask `cmd` to do all the work. It understands the `|` symbol for piping. Or you can create the pipe between the two processes yourself, create both processes, and hook up the pipe between them.  The latter involves calling `CreatePipe` to create the pipe.  And then two calls to `CreateProcess`, one for openssl and one for mplayer. Start by reading some documentation of these API functions, and then some example programs that use pipes.

Comment: You can use pipes with fork()/vfork() for to achieve similar functionality. Have you tried poen() ?

Comment: @sagar No fork on Windows

Comment: Oops i am sorry. What i suggested is for linux. I am really sorry.

Comment: o.k. i did it seccusfuly thank you  @David Heffernan , one more q. how can i open the proccess without a new window? (or with hiding window) ? this is my open proccess code : if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\mplayer.exe", L" - ", 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &suDest, &piDest) == 0) {
  return GetLastError();
 }

Comment: Use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Comment: Straight from the MSDN: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be in control of everything, you need to create both processes (openssl and mplayer) yourself. So that would be two `CreateProcess` calls. Of course, then, you have to create the redirection yourself, as well, and this is done using `CreatePipe`, before creating the processes.

Here is an example (haven't compiled it, may require some tuning):

```
HANDLE proc1_out;
HANDLE proc2_in;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security_attributes;

// create the pipe between the processes
security_attributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
security_attributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE; // pipe handles should be inheritable by sub-processes
security_attributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
CreatePipe(&proc2_in, &proc1_out, &security_attributes, 0);

// create the first process
WCHAR proc1_app[] = L"C:\\openssl.exe";
WCHAR proc1_cmd_line[] = L"openssl enc -aes-128-ofb -d -in C:\\encrypted.bin -iv a2b050be9463 -K 6ba62eb7bb2ccace -nopad";
PROCESS_INFORMATION proc1_info;
STARTUPINFO proc1_startup_info;
ZeroMemory(&proc1_info, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&proc1_startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
proc1_startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
proc1_startup_info.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
proc1_startup_info.hStdOutput = child_output_write; // redirected output
proc1_startup_info.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
proc1_startup_info.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(proc1_app, proc1_cmd_line, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &proc1_startup_info, &proc1_info);

// create the second process
WCHAR proc2_app[] = L"C:\\mplayer.exe";
WCHAR proc2_cmd_line[] = L"mplayer -";
PROCESS_INFORMATION proc2_info;
STARTUPINFO proc2_startup_info;
ZeroMemory(&proc2_info, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&proc2_startup_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
proc2_startup_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
proc2_startup_info.hStdInput = proc2_in; // redirected input
proc2_startup_info.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
proc2_startup_info.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
proc2_startup_info.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(proc2_app, proc2_cmd_line, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &proc2_startup_info, &proc2_info);
```

Notes: in the command line argument passed to CreateProcess, the first "word" in the string must be the process name (this was not what you were doing).

Comment: thank you,i did something like this and its work ' now the q. is how do i prevent mplayer process from opening second cmd window ,how do i do this?

Comment: In the proc2_startup_info, set the *STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW* flag in *dwFlags*, and try setting the *wShowWindow* member to *SW_HIDE*.

Comment: I change wShowWindow to SW_HIDE , What did you mean by this "set the STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW flag in dwFlags"?

Comment: No. Use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Comment: @JECKIRON So, finally how did you set the flags for it to work ?

Comment: @dim CREATE_NO_WINDOW